# Create SSH tunnel using MobaXterm on Windows

Tags: windows, ssh, centos, mobaxterm, jupyter-notebook

I have SSH access to a CentOS server.

There I have a `venv` with Python 3 where I have Jupyter Notebooks installed.

If I create a notebook

```
jupyter notebook
```

It gives me a localhost URL with a specific token.

*Example:* `http://localhost:[PORT]/?token=[TOKEN]`

As I want to access that URL on the local Windows machine, how do I do that using MobaXterm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct procedure is called SSH tunneling. Here's how to do it:

1. Open MobaXterm
2. In the top ribbon, select `Tunneling`

[image]

This pop-up will appear

[image]

3. Press `New SSH tunnel`

[image]

Now configure it accordingly to your needs.

---

Taking the example mentioned in the question, we will have the following:

**Local Clients**

- Forwarded Port: [PORT]

**Remote Server**

- Remote Server: localhost
- Remote Port: [PORT]

**SSH Server**

- SSH server: Name of the server one is connecting to
- SSH login: Username to login to the server
- SSH port: 22